# Paracompact but not Hausdorff

Tags: gn.general-topology, paracompactness

Do paracompact non-Hausdorff spaces admit partions of unity? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no.
Take the "classical" example of the line with two origins. This space is non-Hausdorff, paracompact and doesn't admit partitions of unity.

EDIT: I think the question is a kind of ["duplicate"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19219/smooth-manifolds-that-dont-admit-a-partition-of-unity) . 
Ok, but if you have an example for a non-Hausdorff manifold, which doesn't admit partitions of unity, you have an example for a non-Hausdorff paracompact space with the same property.

First the definition:
The line with two origins is the quotient space of two copies of the real line
$\mathbb{R} \times {a}$ and $\mathbb{R} \times {b}$.
with equivalence relation given by
$(x,a) \sim (x,b)\text{ if }x \neq 0$.
Since all neighbourhoods of $0_a$ intersect all neighbourhoods of $0_b$, it is non-Hausdorff.
However, this space is paracompact, since $\mathbb{R}$ is paracompact.

For the non-existence of a partition of unity: take the open covering $ U = (-\infty,0) \cup \{ 0_a \} \cup (0,\infty)$ and $\tilde{U} = (-\infty,0) \cup \{ 0_b \} \cup (0,\infty)$. Assume, there is a partition of unity subordinate to this cover. Then the value of each origin would have to be $1$ which cannot be true. (Edit: villemoes  was a little faster :-) )

Comment: It was in fact the question to which you linked which made me wonder this. This is not a duplicate question, since Aston insisted on a Hausdorff manifold. How can I see that the example you give is paracompact, and how can I see there is no partition of unity?

Comment: Take any open cover of the "real line" for which there are exactly one open set U_1 containing one copy of 0 (call this 0_1), and one open set U_2 containing the other copy of 0 (0_2). A partition of unity subordinate to this open covering must contain a function f_1 supported in U_1, such that f_1(0_1) = 1, since 0_1 is only contained in this open set. Similarly for 0_2. It follows by continuity that for some small epsilon, we have f_1(epsilon) + f_2(epsilon) > 1, so it is not a partition of unity.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that any $T_1$ space which admits partitions of unity for finite (two element even) covers is Hausdorff:

Proof: Let $x, y \in X$. Let $U = X \ \{x\}, V = X \ \{y\}$. Then let $\{f, g\}$ form a partition of unity with $f$ subordinate to $U$ and $g$ subordinate to $V$. Then $A = \{ t : f(t) > \frac{1}{2} \}$ and $B = \{ t : g(t) > \frac{1}{2} \}$ A and B are disjoint open sets with $y \in A$ and $x \in B$.

Edit: On closer inspection, this if of course just the standard proofs that the existence of partitions of unity for finite covers implies normality + the fact that $T_1$ normal spaces are hausdorff

Answer (score 2):

Paracompact non-Hausdorff spaces *can* admit partitions of unity, but you need a stronger property than paracompactness.  A cover admits a subordinate partition of unity iff it has a locally finite refinement by *cozero* sets.  A cozero set of a space $X$ is a set of a the form $f^{-1}(0,1]$, for a continuous function $f: X \to [0,1]$.

For a space, every open cover having a partition of unity is equivalent to being [fully normal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fully+normal+topological+space).  Fully normal spaces are necessarily paracompact.  Pseudometrizable spaces that are not metrizable are examples of non-Hausdorff fully normal spaces.  Fully normal spaces are necessarily normal, so any compact non-normal space is an example of a paracompact space that is not fully normal.

You can find citations for these results at the nlab's page for [numerable open cover](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/numerable+open+cover).  The results are ultimately due to [Kiiti Morita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiiti_Morita), of Morita equivalence fame.